# What is boudin made from, and how is it made?

Tags: cajun-cuisine, sausages

What is boudin made from, and how is it made?

Comment: See http://tinyurl.com/36fp4uv

Comment: nice url.. since lmgtfy is filtered :P

Comment: Indeed. I'll be trotting out a few of those myself now ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll attempt to expand upon daniel's answer above.

[image: From Wikipedia]

Boudin describes a sausage that is generally created from a blend of beef, rice, and/or pork (["What is Boudin", Cajun French Blog 2009](http://www.cajunfrenchblog.com/2009/01/what-is-boudin/)). Sometimes other types of proteins are added to create variations: Gator, Shrimp, crawfish, etc.

Boudin is widely known to be used in Cajun cooking. Other various types of Boudin exists. As wikipedia defines various different types of boudin:

> - Boudin blanc: A white sausage made of pork without the blood. Pork
>     liver and heart meat are typically included. In Cajun versions, the
>     sausage is made from a pork rice dressing *[...]* In
>     French/Belgian cuisine, the sausage is sauteed or grilled. The
>     Louisiana version is normally simmered or braised, although coating
>     with oil and slow grilling for tailgating is becoming a popular option
>     in New Orleans and Baton Rouge.
> - Boudin noir: A dark-hued blood sausage, containing pork, pig blood, and other ingredients. Variants of the boudin noir occur in French, Belgian, Cajun and Catalan
>     cuisine *[...]*
> - Shrimp Boudin: Similar to crawfish boudin, it is made by adding the shrimp to rice *[...]*
> - [4] Boudin rouge: In Louisiana cuisine, a sausage
>     similar to boudin blanc, but with pork blood added to it. This
>     originated from the French boudin noir.
> - Brown Rice Boudin: Taste is very similar to traditional pork boudin, except this boudin > is made with a brown-rice substitute for those looking to cut down on white rice intake.

Answer (score 1):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boudin